# Combine two Deep learning model CNN amd LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I build a model consisting of one CNN and one LSTM. CNN to extract the features and pass that to LSTM. I am working with binary classification problem , the input for CNN is TF-IDF.

```
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Flatten,Activation
    from tensorflow.keras.metrics import CategoricalAccuracy, AUC
    from tensorflow import keras
    import tensorflow as tf
    from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Conv1D,MaxPooling1D
    from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=(1500, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5,validation_split=0.1,verbose=1,batch_size=512)
```

the error is as follows :

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 1, 1500)

Comment: What about `np.transpose(X_train, axes = [0, 2, 1])`, apparently the axes are misordered.

Comment: Thanks, It works but is very slow. I have just 1800 records for train part  and 5 epoch takes 30 minutes

Comment: change input_shape at Conv1D ```input_shape=(1500, 1))``` to ```input_shape=(1 , 1500))```

Comment: Dear Mohammad Ahmed https://stackoverflow.com/users/7746219/mohammad-ahmed,  during the compile the model the following error appears when I change the input_shape to (1,1500) :       ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for '{{node conv1d_3/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d_3/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d_3/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,1500], [1,5,1500,128].